# Capture XHR with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS with jQuery and I'm wondering if it's possible to capture an XMLHttpRequest as it's passed to the browser, without initiating the POST/GET yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are simple jQuery functions that will let you modify AJAX requests before they are sent, but they only target AJAX requests initiated by jQuery. To catch all AJAX requests on a page, use the following basic JS-only way:

```
(function(open){
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, username, password) {
        // modify the variables here as needed or use 'this` keyword to change the XHR object or add event listeners to it
        open.call(this, method, url, async, username, password);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

You could also rewrite the XHR send() function:

```
(function(send){
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(body) {
       // your code
       send.call(this, body);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

Basically, this code needs to be the FIRST code that runs on your page. All subsequent XHR requests will go through the rewritten function(s), allowing you to change any parameters, etc.

Note: if you wish to target some versions of IE, you need to implement similar code for the ActiveXObject that IE uses for AJAX.

Comment: Word of caution to future users: code in iframes gets their own copy of the window object, you need to hook XHR in them too.

Answer (score 1):

[ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) sounds good, but never used it. This filters the request before going to the server. You can then use [pipe](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) to modify, what you want, when the request returns:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR){
    jqXHR.pipe(function(data){
        //modify the data the way you want
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Phantom's `onResourceReceived` callback is invoked for all XHR/AJAX requests made by the page. Twice, actually, once with stage="start", once with stage="end". It won't give you the content, but it will capture the URL.